# Up and over garage door transformation

Tags: doors, metal, garage-door

This up and over door is working properly, but I would like to make the house more accessible.

This door is a bit heavy and you have to work against gravity to open in entirely. My idea was to cut it in two pieces, make some modifications to the frame,  keep one third hinged to the left side as it is currently, and hinge the two other thirds to the right side. The walls are made of bricks. Also it would make the door simpler and easier to service by getting rid of all those springs and rails.

My main concern is about hinging the right panel to the wall. How can I determine if the door itself will be strong enough to support its own weight and not twist ? The right panel is a 2mx2m square (6'6"). I'm not sure about the hinges either.

[image: Garage door]

Comment: My guess would be that it'll need some form of support mounted onto it to keep it upright. It's currently held up by the rails on the sides and from the panels beneath each other. Although it'll still hold itself up from the panels, you'll need to recreate the side supports that were the rails. Re-support it, add some wheels to the ends to help with opening it, and find hinges strong enough to support the load. The wheels will also help hold the weight from bearing on the hinges.